# SQL retornando vazio, if($id == "" or $id == null or $id == 0) porém só cai no else

Tags: php, mysqli

Boa tarde galera, primeiramente obrigado por me ajudar, estou terminando um sistema e tenho um problema que acredito ser muito simples, mas não consigo resolver, ja tentei diversas maneiras de alterar o if, mas não vai

o código é este

```
public function verificavenda(){
    $c= new conectar();
    $conexao=$c->conexao();

    $sql="SELECT idvenda from vendas order by idvenda desc";

    $result=mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

    $id=mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];

    if($id == "" or $id == null or $id == 0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return $id + 1;
    }
}
```

depois do primeiro $id criado, ele sempre cai no else, até ai beleza, é o que queria

agora quando não tem nada no banco de dados, da o seguinte erro > "trying to access array offset on value of type null"

e em vez de cair no IF cai no else da mesma maneira, retornando um erro na pagina em vez de retornar apenas o numero

já perdi algumas horas, e não encontro o trem, rs obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

O erro acontece pois você não tem registro no banco de dados. Com isso a função não retorna um array e sim um primitivo. O que causa um erro na tentativa de acessar o index '0'.

Verifique se a versão abaixo te ajuda.

```php
public function verificavenda(){
    $c= new conectar();
    $conexao=$c->conexao();

    $sql="SELECT idvenda from vendas order by idvenda desc";

    $result=mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    if(!$row){
        return 1;
    }
    $id = $row[0];

    return $id + 1;
}
```

Comment: bom diaa
funcionou perfeitamente, irei, mas gostaria de agradecer mesmo por ter me respondido o pprque do erro, pelo menos com este erro não sofrerei mais

obrigado meu rei!

Comment: Disponha... Estamos aqui para ajudar. Se puder marcar a resposta como aceita, agradeço.